# How to use shader from ShaderToy in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, shader, vertex-shader, shadertoy

I want to use [this shader from ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtdXzr) in my Three.js project, but I can't get it working.

Can you help me converting some values and setting up the fragmentShader, vertexShader and uniforms?

I already tried converting some values, but it didn't work.

Comment: I did it years ago with a [matrix shader](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/matrix.html). maybe taking a look at it will help you. There's a link to the original at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that *some* people doesn't like this type of questions. Probably because they struggled with the implementation themselves and now you have to struggle too... My point of view is slightly different, that I had to struggle with the implementation of shaders etc. doesn't mean that others have to suffer too... but whatever. In fact, if Inigo Quilez thought the same, he wouldn't publish his code.
On the other hand, however, you won't be able to do much with this logic if you try to *copy and paste* someone else's code and treat it as your own, or even worse, present it to your potential customers as written by you (don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you do this, this is just a general hypothesis). This logic is very short-sighted, especially in this environment (3D, webgl, 3, etc.) where there are usually the same people on the forums. Secondly, usually these works, whether on ShaderToy or other such platforms, are difficult or often impossible to implement in real life, in an end-client project. They are simply too expensive, often even for a desktop.

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

<canvas class="webglHH"> </canvas>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webglHH");

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 3;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true,
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
renderer.render(scene, camera);

const vertexShader = `
  void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
`;

const fragmentShader = `
// Created by inigo quilez - iq/2013 : https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dl3zn
// License Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
// Messed up by Weyland

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;

void main() {
  vec2 uv = -1.0 + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y;
  vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
      float pha = sin(float(i) * 546.13 + 1.0) * 0.5 + 0.5;
      float siz = pow(sin(float(i) * 651.74 + 5.0) * 0.5 + 0.5, 4.0);
      float pox = sin(float(i) * 321.55 + 4.1) * iResolution.x / iResolution.y;
      float rad = 0.1 + 0.5 * siz + sin(pha + siz) / 4.0;
      vec2 pos = vec2(pox + sin(iTime / 15. + pha + siz), -1.0 - rad + (2.0 + 2.0 * rad) * mod(pha + 0.3 * (iTime / 7.) * (0.2 + 0.8 * siz), 1.0));
      float dis = length(uv - pos);
      vec3 col = mix(vec3(0.194 * sin(iTime / 6.0) + 0.3, 0.2, 0.3 * pha), vec3(1.1 * sin(iTime / 9.0) + 0.3, 0.2 * pha, 0.4), 0.5 + 0.5 * sin(float(i)));
      float f = length(uv - pos) / rad;
      f = sqrt(clamp(1.0 + (sin((iTime) * siz) * 0.5) * f, 0.0, 1.0));
      color += col.zyx * (1.0 - smoothstep(rad * 0.15, rad, dis));
  }
  color *= sqrt(1.5 - 0.5 * length(uv));
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
`;

const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    iTime: { value: 0.0 },
    iResolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2() },
  },
  vertexShader,
  fragmentShader,
});

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3);
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);

function windowResize() {
  const newResolution = new THREE.Vector2(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight
  );
  material.uniforms.iResolution.value.copy(newResolution);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  material.uniforms.iTime.value += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
windowResize();
animate();
</script>
```