# How to Implement ShaderToy in Threejs ShaderMaterial?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, vertex-shader, shadertoy, shadermaterial

I am very new in Threejs as well as in ShaderMaterial. And also zero knowledge in GLSL or C/C++.

How to convert the [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MtVGDh) code into Threejs uniforms, vertexShader, fragmentShader?

I want to make dynamic the iChannel2 I mean this is envMap, bounce time etc. (Possible dynamic fields).

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700479/how-to-use-shader-from-shadertoy-in-three-js

Comment: Could you please convert this particular code?

Comment: "_I am very new in Threejs as well as in ShaderMaterial. And also zero knowledge in GLSL..._"  I think that you should start from much more easier implementations then that shader which you provided...

Comment: I went though the same process of trying to learn/implement shaders in three.js a few years ago. I made a blog post titled [Experimenting with Three.js shaders and the ShaderMaterial](https://2pha.com/blog/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial/) sort of documenting it. It may help you.